# In which languages are string chars stored contiguously in memory?

Tags: string, programming-languages

In C, a string, `char *` is represented contiguously in memory. The next address is the next char. In what other languages is this the case for the standard string implementation?

Comment: In Haskell, I believe, the default string type essentially uses a linked list of characters (unicode code points, really)

Comment: The Ada language defines its String type as "type String is array (Positive range <>)  of Character;"     Ada arrays are stored contiguously.